# How do you resize (particularly make smaller) program icons (active windows) in the Windows XP Taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, taskbar

I'd like to narrow the icons for currently running programs in the Taskbar.  I'd like to achieve a greater density in that area but I don't want to group similar items.

Is this possible?  I've some up short when Googling.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. The currently running programs shrink when you have more than can fit on the task bar automatically so that it will fit more of them.

Comment: You wan't to disable grouping, but don't want text on taskbar items?

Comment: @blsub6 - on XP they don't appear to shrink - it creates a second row of icons.

Comment: @schöppi - having no text is ok.  I just the items to be overall smaller.

Comment: @Matt were you ever able to find a solution to this, or is this even still a need?